# Which is the Go way, PutUint32 or use >> operator directly?

Tags: go, binary

This is two ways to get the same 4 bytes:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/binary"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  i := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32([]byte{1, 2, 3, 0})
  bs := make([]byte, 4)
  binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bs, uint32(i))
  fmt.Println(bs[0] == 1 && bs[1] == 2 && bs[2] == 3 && bs[3] == 0)

  bs = []byte{byte(i & 0x000000ff),
    byte(i >> 8 & 0x000000ff),
    byte(i >> 16 & 0x000000ff),
    byte(i >> 24)}
  fmt.Println(bs[0] == 1 && bs[1] == 2 && bs[2] == 3 && bs[3] == 0)
}
```

They both work. But which is the way the Go community would say is best?

Comment: `bs = []byte{byte(i), byte(i >> 8), byte(i >> 16), byte(i >> 24)}`

Comment: nice edit, i like it!

Comment: Both are used, so it's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look inside the Go standard library:

```
func (littleEndian) PutUint32(b []byte, v uint32) {
    _ = b[3] // early bounds check to guarantee safety of writes below
    b[0] = byte(v)
    b[1] = byte(v >> 8)
    b[2] = byte(v >> 16)
    b[3] = byte(v >> 24)
}
```

And see the `Package binary`documentation:

> This package favors **simplicity** over **efficiency**. Clients that require high-performance serialization, especially for large data structures, should look at more advanced solutions such as the encoding/gob package or protocol buffers.

Which way we should go, depends on a problem we are trying to solve:
When the **efficiency** is not the main concern (of the problem we are trying to solve with programming), The **simplicity** is the way to go (because **less bug** is the main goal here):

1. You may use the Go standard library function `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32` with an array (note you may use an array `[4]byte{}` here, for **efficiency** and **simplicity** over `make([]byte, 4)`):

```
        var v uint32 = 0x4030201
        ary := [4]byte{}
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(ary[:], v)
        fmt.Println(ary) // [1 2 3 4]
```

2. You may use the Go standard library function `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32` with a slice:

```
        var v uint32 = 0x4030201
        b := make([]byte, 4)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, v)
        fmt.Println(b) // [1 2 3 4]
```

3. You may write it directly (**efficiency**, since no library function call):

```
        var v uint32 = 0x4030201
        a := [4]byte{
            byte(v),
            byte(v >> 8),
            byte(v >> 16),
            byte(v >> 24),
        }
        fmt.Println(a) // [1 2 3 4]
```

4. You may use `unsafe.Pointer` (Just for **efficiency** or compatiblity or ...):

```
        var v uint32 = 1
        a := (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))
        a[0] = 100        // same memory (Like `union` in the C language)
        fmt.Println(a, v) // &[100 0 0 0] 100
```

5. You may use `unsafe.Pointer` and make a copy in one-line (so not a `union`):

```
        var v uint32 = 0x4030201
        a := *(*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))
        fmt.Println(a) // [1 2 3 4]
```

6. You may use `unsafe.Pointer` with the `copy` to a slice:

```
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    copy(b, (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))[:])
```

Try it all [here](https://play.golang.org/p/mj52QeXwKtj)

---

Benchmark:

```
BenchmarkFn1-8          580469606                1.94 ns/op
BenchmarkFn2-8          568699358                2.06 ns/op
BenchmarkFn3-8          604883466                1.86 ns/op
BenchmarkFn4-8          824232160                1.33 ns/op
BenchmarkFn5-8          626357875                1.82 ns/op
BenchmarkFn6-8          622969119                1.82 ns/op
BenchmarkFn7-8          469203398                2.35 ns/op
BenchmarkFn8-8          637403140                1.80 ns/op
BenchmarkFn9-8          647179550                1.80 ns/op
```

`main.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "unsafe"
)

// 1.94 ns/op
func fn1(v uint32) [4]byte {
    ary := [4]byte{}
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(ary[:], v)
    return ary
}

// 2.06 ns/op
func fn2(v uint32) []byte {
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, v)
    return b
}

// 1.86 ns/op
func fn3(v uint32) [4]byte {
    a := [4]byte{
        byte(v),
        byte(v >> 8),
        byte(v >> 16),
        byte(v >> 24),
    }
    return a
}

// 1.33 ns/op
func fn4(v uint32) *[4]byte {
    a := (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))
    return a
}

// 1.82 ns/op
func fn5(v uint32) [4]byte {
    a := *(*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))
    return a
}

// 1.82 ns/op
func fn6(v uint32) []byte {
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    copy(b, (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))[:])
    return b
}

// 2.35 ns/op
func fn7(v uint32) [4]byte {
    b := [4]byte{}
    copy(b[:], (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))[:])
    return b
}

// 1.80 ns/op
func fn8(v uint32) *[4]byte {
    b := [4]byte{}
    copy(b[:], (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))[:])
    return &b
}

//1.80 ns/op
func fn9(v uint32) []byte {
    b := [4]byte{}
    copy(b[:], (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))[:])
    return b[:]
}

func main() {}
```

`main_test.go` file:

```
package main

import "testing"

var result int

func BenchmarkFn1(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn1(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn2(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn2(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn3(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn3(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn4(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn4(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn5(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn5(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn6(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn6(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn7(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn7(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn8(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn8(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}

func BenchmarkFn9(b *testing.B) {
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r := fn9(uint32(i))
        sum += int(r[0]) + int(r[1]) + int(r[2]) + int(r[3])
    }
    result = sum
}
```

---

## Conclusion

Ultra fast and unsafe (shared memory e.g. `C union` and it may differ from little-endian to big-endian system):

```
a := (*[4]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))
```

Fast and safe (copy of v as an array):

```
a := [4]byte{byte(v), byte(v >> 8), byte(v >> 16), byte(v >> 24)}
```

Simple and fast (copy of v as an array using the standard library):

```
    ary := [4]byte{}
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(ary[:], v)
```

Beautiful (copy of v as a slice using the standard library):

```
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, v)
```